# How can I hide all posts that don't have a thumbnail?

Tags: filters, hooks

I want to prevent posts that dont have thumbnails from showing on the homepage, category page, archive, etc.

Using something like

```
if (get_the_post_thumbnail_url() != "") {
    //don't insert post
}
```

What filter / hook should I use?

Comment: A more performant and scalable version of this question would be "How do I show all posts that *do* have a thumbnail?". Always query for what you want, not what you don't want

Answer (score 3):

> What filter / hook should I use?

You can use the `pre_get_posts` action hook.

Following [Tom's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) comment on the question about querying for what you want, maybe set `meta_query` to `_thumbnail_id`.

I would also `(` group `)` the conditionals to read:

"Is *both* not admin and is main query, AND is either home, category, or archive."

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'thumbnails_only' );

function thumbnails_only( $query ) {
    if ( ( ! $query->is_admin && $query->is_main_query() ) && ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_category() || $query->is_archive() ) ) {

    $meta_query = array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                )
            );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
   }
}
```

may want to replace `is_home()` with `is_front_page()` [depending on your site settings.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/#usage)

Comment: Just a note: querying by meta key might [hurt your performance](https://metabox.io/custom-fields-vs-custom-taxonomies/).

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for can be expensive. You can not check if a post has thumbnail or not unless the query is ran. After that, if you exclude it from the query that has already been executed, it will mess with the pagination.

What you can do is to run a query once (before the main query runs), but don't use it to output any content. Then, search for the posts without any thumbnail in that particular query, save their IDs to an array and exclude them from the main query.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_no_thumbnails' );
function exclude_no_thumbnails( $query ) {
    // Check if we are on the main query
    if (!is_admin() && ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive() ) ){
        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_no_thumbnails' );
        // Get a list of the posts in the query
        $posts = get_posts( $query->query );
        // Create an empty array to save the IDs of posts without a thumbnail
        $ids = array();
        // Run a loop and check the thumbnails
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            if(!has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
                $ids[] = $post->ID;
            }
        }
        // Now time to exclude these posts from the query
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $ids );
    }
}
```

This will probably cost you an extra query. Caching can save your day here.